# Откуда берётся это 'e' ?

Tags: jquery

Пожалуйста, объясните

```
$('#myid').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   //any code
   if (e.target('#subid') { //any action }
});
```

Откуда берется эта **e**? Что это по сути? Объект? Тогда чем она отличается от **this**? Я так понимаю это какие-то нативные объекты `jQuery`, где поискать описание не знаю как сформулировать вопрос. В коде встречал так-же

```
$('#anyid').click(function(index, e){ // any action });
```

откуда то берется индекс элемента... для меня загадка. Вроде в практике знаю что "это" делает а в теории не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это объект события. [Свойства объекта событие](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/properties).

Answer (score 3):

Просто попробуйте на этой же странице в консоли браузера выполнить этот код и сравните первый и второй результаты:

```
$('#editor').click(
    function (e) { 
        console.log("Это e:");
        console.log(e);
        console.log("А вот это this:");
        console.log(this);
    });
```